# Monitoring changes in HTML textarea element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Unfortunately, the "change" event for a <textarea> only fires when the element looses focus.

I'd like to fire an alert() when the content of it actually changes, while the element is still focussed.

Here's what I've got:

```
var $editor = $("#editor")
 .keydown(function () {
  $editor.data("before-keydown", $editor.val());
 })
 .keyup(function () {
  if ($editor.data("before-keydown") !== $editor.val()) {
   alert("content has changed");
  }
 });
```

Is there any better way to determine when the contents of the <textarea> change?

Comment: What's wrong with your method? Is if failing somwhere?

Comment: You may also want to handle the "cut" and "paste" events.

Comment: What is before-keydown? A variable, an ID, a class?

Comment: I don't work with this sort of thing *that* much but it occurs to me that it might be easier to just worry about "keypress" instead of both "keyup" and "keydown".

Comment: If that $ in your code is for jQuery you could try the maxlength plugin: http://www.stjerneman.com/demo/maxlength-with-jquery

Comment: @josh: It's not failing--just wondering if I'm reinventing the wheel. :)
@Pointy: This does handle cut and paste--both cutting and pasting require keydown and up.
@matt: That's the data member name. Not familiar with $.fn.data()?
@Pointy: How can I compare the before and after if I'm only checking keypress? I can't.

Comment: @something: maxlength has absolutely nothing to do with this, but thanks.

Comment: *"both cutting and pasting require keydown and up."*, not when I use my context menu or the browser's edit menu. That's probably why @Pointy mentioned it :-)

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the HTML5 `oninput` event, it trumps key events for capturing text input and most browsers have supported it for a while now.  The exception is Internet Explorer, although it's in the latest Internet Explorer 9 preview.  Internet Explorer can emulate this event, however, using its own proprietary event `onpropertychange`, which will fire every time the `value` property changes.

`oninput` will fire for all forms of input, such as cut, paste, spelling auto-correct, drag and drop, etc.  Since you're using jQuery, you could take a look at [my plugin](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event) which handles the differences and normalizes the event as much as possible for Internet Explorer and older browsers.  This would make your code look something like this:

```
var $editor = $("#editor").input(function() {
    alert("content has changed");
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9YcPu/**

nb: it's also worth mentioning that `oninput` doesn't fire if the value doesn't change, for instance if you highlight a section of text and copy/paste the same selection over the top so that the text stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) attribute from jquery.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#editor").keypress(function() {
            alert('Handler for .keypress() called.');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```